# Absolute Path vs. Relative Path - put relative contents link in post

Tags: hyperlink, absolute-path

When I write a post, I want to link to some other related posts in the content.
I have two option for link: 
1. "http://www.example.com/related-post-slug" 
2. "/related-post-slug" 
Is there any difference between these in this situation? for SEO or something else...?

Answer (score 0):

Many reasons why you wouldn't want to use absolute path but perhaps some benefit from an SEO perspective.  http://www.dirigodev.com/blog/seo-web-best-practices/relative-vs-absolute-urls-seo/